# I was using node mongo db now I try to use the same database in mysql with sequelize using async await but I have this problem... plaese

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, api, sequelize.js

I just want to consult a table of products wanted to know if it can be used with async await in javascript with nodejs express and sequelize
it is a api

```
     import { ProductoModel } from "../models/ProductoModel.js";
        const listar = async (req,res) => {
        try {
                const listaProductos = await ProductoModel.findAll();
                res.send({msg: "lista de productos"});
                res.json(listaProductos);
            } catch (error) {
                res.json({msg: error.msg});
            }
        };
        export {listar};
```

> error=
> (C:\Users\VE\Desktop\REACTjs\APPInversionesTovar\node\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
> at listar (file:///C:/Users/VE/Desktop/REACTjs/APPInversionesTovar/node/controllers/productoController.js:10:13)

Answer (score 0):

I see here you are using `res.send` and `res.json` separately, both will send the response. try using this after the `findAll` query:

```js
    res.json({msg: "lista de productos", data: listaProductos})
```

Comment: yes... thanks although I find it strange because when I use it with mongodb it works like this.   i love bro